# Expression for kinetic energy of gas per molecule

Tags: ideal-gas, rotational-kinematics, kinetic-theory

The average kinetic energy (KE) per molecule of a gas is $\frac{3}{2}kT$. While finding this we do

$$ \text{ Average KE} =\frac{1}{2} M \frac{1}{N}\sum v^2=\frac{3}{2}kT$$
But why do we not add rotational kinetic energy here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression you quote is for a ideal monatomic gas, and we get $C_v = 3/2$ for the three degrees of freedom. For ideal diatomic gases we do indeed have to count rotational degrees of freedom and we get $C_v = 5/2$. See the Wikipedia article on [ideal gases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

For any Ideal Gas:-

- *PV = 2/3E*
- *PV = (γ-1)U*

where U = E + R (Internal energy),

E = 1/2mvᵣₘₛ² (avg. **translational** Kinetic energy),

& R is **rotational** Kinetic energy.

For eg:   A diatomic gas with *γ = 7/5* has *PV = 2/3E*  &  *PV = (7/5 - 1)U*.

Therefore, *2/3E = 2/5U*

**OR**   *E = 3/5U*

**CONCLUSION #1**:  Translational kinetic energy of a diatomic gas makes up 3/5th of it's internal energy.

From  **equation of state**, *PV = NKᵦT*

Therefore, *NKᵦT = 2/3E*

**OR**   *E = 3/2NKᵦT*

**CONCLUSION #2**: **Avg. Translational Kinteic Energy Per Molecule** (i.e. *E/N = 3/2KᵦT*) is related only to Temperature & is independent of pressure, volume or nature of gas.

FINAL CONCLUSION: Temperature depends on **Avg. TRANSLATIONAL kinetic energy** in ideal cases, whether mono, di or poly-atomic.

Thanks!!

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen someone use $\beta$ as a replacement for the subscript $B$ in Boltzmann's constant.